# Best way to find first parse success in a string using attoparsec Haskell library

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I want to do that:

```
findFirst :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe a
findFirst parser text = 
    search (maybeResult . parse parser . pack $ text) text where
            search _ []       = Nothing 
            search Nothing  _ = findFirst parser (DL.drop 1 text)  
            search res _      = res
```

It is working fine, but are there a easier (more beautyful) way in the world of attoparsec?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving code that already works.  It would be better received on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.